# Basic compound lift based workout composition and scheduling

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, recovery, compound-exercises

I'm `25  years old , 5 feet 11 inches tall and weigh 235 pounds`. Over the `last couple of months` I have been `following a 4 day workout program` based on the following schedule :

```
Monday  : Chest
Tuesday : Back
Wednesday : Rest
Thursday : Triceps
Friday : Shoulders
```

The reason for skipping leg day is that my leg muscles are decently developed , hence I don't target them specifically.

I would like to change this schedule into a 3 day program.
How do  I go about it and what all compound exercises do I incorporate for each body part ?

TIA.

Comment: I'm having serious troubles taking this seriously when you have an entire day dedicated to triceps, but no legs. Regardless of the state of your legs. Triceps get worked during both chest day and shoulder day.

Comment: You need to start with goals and have a program designed to reach those goals. So edit your question to state what you're goal is, and you'll get better responses.

Answer (score 2):

> The reason for skipping leg day is that my leg muscles are decently
>   developed , hence I don't target them specifically.

Honestly I'd doubt that. Your "leg muscles" consist a large variety of muscles. The obvious ones like your quads and hamstrings are there, but I don't know how you can say that your [iliopsoas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliopsoas) is sufficiently strong and flexible. Also, it's quite difficult to strengthen your lower back and abdominal muscles without engaging your hips, which in turn engage your legs.

> I would like to change this schedule into a 3 day program. How do I go
>   about it and what all compound exercises do I incorporate for each
>   body part ?

Compound exercises, are by definition, not concerned with each body part. I would encourage you to look into one of the numerous [highly effective strength training programs out there](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091).

For the most part, these will use squats, pressing (bench and overhead), deadlifts, and rows (or cleans). It might field weird to ditch the classic isolation and body part split routine that you're doing, but take heart in the fact that there's simply no way you'll be small and squat twice your body weight. You'll be powerful, big, balanced, and spend less time in the gym.

Answer (score 0):

**How do I go about it and what all compound exercises do I incorporate for each body part ?**

That is simple. Choose a **full body strength routine**, SL 5x5, ICF 5x5, SS, PPL and etc.

With that said, please continue doing your squats, lunges, leg extension and etc. Keep training your legs. Don't worry, **your legs will not get as huge as those Mr Olympia**.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: He asked for a change to his schedule into a 3 day program, and also asked what compound exercises to be included. The programs provided are pretty much packed with compound movements.

Comment: This could be a better answer if you could outline the programs (Or at the least not abbreviate for people that don't know them), and why they fit the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

Triceps and shoulders are smaller muscles than chest and back so combine triceps and shoulders in one day like:

day1 : Chest 
day2 : Back 
day3 : Shoulders/Arms(triceps-biceps)