# Getting into shape without becoming a body builder

Tags: gym

I'm starting the gym in 4 days, I've recently gained a bit of weight (1 stone) and I am trying to lose it and tone up... Does anyone have any advice on gym-related things and also dietary stuff?

I hear that challenges are great where you follow a certain diet and training regime

My goal is to lose 1-2 stone, my plan is to go to the gym for 1 hour everyday

I don't know the first thing about healthy foods, can anyone recommend any good challenges / fitness regimes / diet plans that actually work?

Comment: your questions is extremely broad; try to specify your goals, what you want to achieve and what exactly it is that you want to learn. StackExchange sites are different than most other online resources in that they aim at giving fact based answers to specific questions, rather than giving opinionated advices. Take a look at [this page](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [this page](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good strength training program for a beginner?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/whats-a-good-strength-training-program-for-a-beginner)

Comment: Very broad, as there's a ton of great answers-and which one is right for you depends on you.  Personally, I want to draw attention to your goal-why do you want to lose 1-2 stone?

Comment: This is so easy. You're not able to get a bodybuilder's body. You would have to work so ridiculously hard, and eat so precisely measured meals, that within a week, you'd start to question it all. And that's if you actually wanted it. Since you don't, there is absolutely a 0% chance of it happening.