# Taking time off work to weight lift

Tags: weightlifting, squats, snatch, power-cleans

I need opinion / advice / information...

basically, I want to take a week or more off work, to weightlift everyday, and increase my lifts as much as I can. Even during work days, I squat in the morning and in the evening minimum, so I'm not really so worried about the intensity and I don't really want to go on holiday.

I can't really find a decent weightlifting camp around in the UK, or one that doesn't cost so much.

What are some opinions on what I could do? or what you may think on what I want to do.

If anyone does know of any weight lifting training camps around in the UK please post.

much appreciated on any comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about weightlifting camp locations.

Comment: @JohnP yeah sure, it is off topic I suppose, my apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to stop you in two places. First, this line:

> I want to take a week or more off work, to weightlift everyday, and
>   increase my lifts as much as I can.

At maximum, and this is if you're on a great program, you'll gain 4%, tops. If you're an [intermediate lifter](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/SquatStandards.html) (which I'm guessing your not just yet), you'll gain maybe 3%, tops.

> I squat in the morning and in the evening minimum...

Unless you're a very high level [Olympic lifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_weightlifting), I don't think there is any training program that would advise a schedule like that. The only reason Olympic lifters can do that is because they're not doing maximum strength effort on technical lifts during multi-sessions-per-day.

Since you said you're in the UK, and want to get strong, I would recommend these steps for you:

1. Contact the [Great Britain Powerlifting Association](http://www.gbpf.org.uk/). Under "organisation" you'll find links to area coaches and gyms. Email them and explain your training history (be 100% honest), your goals, and the time you can allow.
2. If you get a qualified coach (from the link above, someone who can point to high level athletes they've trained, not some guy at the big box gym with a polo), follow what they tell you. If you decide to pave your own road in the beginning, which plenty of people do, make sure you pick [a proven strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091).

An old coach of mine explained athletics like filling up a bathtub, one teaspoon at a time. Each training and rest day matters, but more so the cumulative nature of doing it for months and years is what separates weekend warriors from amateur and professional athletes.

Comment: I will treasure that advice your coach gave you. Thank you for this answer

Comment: @user2405469 , thanks. If you consider it an answer, please click the little "accept answer" checkbox up there.