# Exercising assisting muscle then main muscle day after day?

Tags: rest, bench-press

So here is my question: Say on Monday you do the bench press and on Tuesday you do the shoulder press. Can this be okay or is it not enough rest because shoulders and triceps assist with the bench press. That is my question.

Comment: get a real training program http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, its **highly debatable**.

Some factors you may want to consider:-

- How heavy did you train, in this case did you go heavy for your bench or did you go light?
- How much volume(sets/reps) is done on that day(for your bench)?
- Are you eating in a surplus(eating more than your maintenance).
- How fast can your body recover(physical and central nervous system fatigue).
- Your mood for the day.

With that said, if you really want to know more, you could try doing it to see if your body is capable of doing so.