# Quarterback training?

Tags: stretching, arms, hands, football

I am not sure it this is the right site,but can anyone tell me some exercises without weights,like stretches,to train my hand and arm so i can be a good quarterback. Thanks

Comment: maybe consider this: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091

Comment: You really think stretching your hand an arm is all it takes? And I hate to tell you, but if you want to be a good football player, a large portion of your life will be spent in the weight room.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be the one who has to tell you this, but I have to agree with John P, at least to a degree. Football players have to be packed with a lot of muscles, which is easier attainable with weights. Some exercises that would enhance arm and hand strength probably include bicep curls, bench press, shoulder press, and dumbbell rows. I would honestly be more worried about your shoulders than your arms in order to be a good quarterback, however, because they are the primary muscles used when throwing a football. To enhance shoulder strength, you could do decline flyes, side lateral raises, front raises, and shoulder press. And if you really don't want to lift for whatever reason, push ups, chin ups, pull ups, arm circles, and dips could all be options in order to enhance arm, hand, and shoulder muscles. Also, consider increasing your calories, because it will also make you bigger. I hope this helps you and good luck with your games.

Comment: Thanks i found somother stuff put this would be good too