# Smoking marijuana while working out?

Tags: bodybuilding, health, smoking

So I am 20, I recently began smoking marijuana and am now doing it during my training sessions(in between sets, for example). When I am doing a curl I might lift with one hand and smoke with the other hand. I lift at my friend's basement(we both never went on to college but did graduate high school if that matters), anyway, so we don't get in trouble or anything. Is there health risks involved with this?

Comment: Why do you curl with one hand, and smoke with the other? Can't you just curl with both hands, and keep the joint in your mouth?

Comment: @Alec I could not stop laughing at this comment. Comedy gold.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, I think your biggest issue will be cognitive impairment.

The image of two kids in a basement toking and curling is honestly quite hilarious, and probably isn't going to be too much of a problem in and of itself. More to the point:

1. Curling is a terribly inefficient exercise unless you're a rather advanced body builder, which I'm going to safely assume you're not. You'd be much better of doing [a compound lifting program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091).
2. Smoking dope actually in the middle of a [compound lifting program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) is dangerous because you need your focus and concentration. [Marijuana impairs your motor functions](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/600655), and when you lift heavy you need everything firing properly.

Health risks associated with marijuana in general are out of scope for this StackExchange site, but I'd encourage you to look around for [authoritative sources](http://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/treatment/cam/hp/cannabis-pdq) and [peer reviewed medicine](https://nccih.nih.gov/health/marijuana) to make your decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is legal to smoke marijuana where you live, I would suggest waiting until after you work out to enjoy a smoke. Smoking while your body is under stress from the weightlifting makes it harder to reap the benefits of working out.