# Suggest better workout schedule to get ripped body

Tags: diet, workout-routines, muscle

Currently, I'm doing strength exercises and cardio exercises on alternate days, 6 days a week.

In **strength exercise:**

1. Chest & triceps.
2. Biceps & back.
3. Legs & shoulder.

4-5 exercises with alternate sets (3 sets with 10 reps) for each part.

In **cardio exercise:**

1. 2km running.
2. 10 min cycling.
3. 10 min stepper.
4. Plank exercise.
5. Abs workout.

### Update

My diet is simple. I'm using cooked lentils, eggs, tofu, raw nuts, milk in my **daily protein diet**. I'm not using any whey protein and other diet related plans and precautions. Suggest me and enrich my knowledge towards diet which is very important for body.

I got enough muscle bulk but body is mixed with fat and muscle bulk. **Need better workout schedule or suggestions to get ripped body**.

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't seem to be the workout. It looks just fine, and without more details it's hard to advise you any better.

However, changing your workout schedule is probably not the way to go if you want a *ripped body*. Diet plays a major role, and I am a bit surprised that you didn't even mention it in your original post.

There are a bunch of them out there, but the main idea to focus on limiting carbs (and calories more generally), and on keeping a decent protein intake (between 1.5g to 2g per kilo).

In short, continue working you, but pay attention to what you eat.

Answer (score 0):

Your workout routine is fine, but maintain your diet in proper way because nutrition is very important. Make sure you consume 200 gm protein and 0.5 gm carbs * (body weight in pounds) a day.

Instead of consuming 3 big meals, divide them into 6 small meals which helps you to maintain your metabolism at constant rate. 
Basically your diet plan during workout days should be **High Protein and Low Carbs** and during recovery day **High Carbs Low Protein**.

Comment: Just curious...what do you base your recommendations on?  How did you come up with the numbers you posted?

Comment: Even I had same bulk body with fat and my trainer recommended those number and it actually helped me to get shredded.

Comment: Keep in mind, those numbers may have worked for you, but, there's no way to say that they will work for the OP.  Nutrition is a very **individual** science.

Comment: Ok I agree with you, but how one need to determine that how much protein and carbs is required?