# Fitness measurement for appropriate heights?

Tags: physique

What is the general fitness measurement for biceps, chest, stomach, hip and soon on.

And what weight is advisory for 180 cm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than chasing size, which is largely dependent upon your genetics, you should consider aiming for [strength standards](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards.htm).

Even if you are "only training for strength", you will pack on a large amount of muscle and will do so in a comprehensive way if you use [a proper training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091).

The BMI standards say that for your height, you should be anywhere from 60-78 kilograms.

More importantly than that however, would be focusing on strength standards and body fat. If you can get stronger and stronger while keeping your body fat under 15%, I think you'll find yourself pretty happy with the results.

I'm giving you very generalized advice, but following it for a year will put you in a terrific spot to either go into body building, athletics, or just long term health and fitness.