# Chest/Abs training for a thin young man (4 times for 6 months)

Tags: training

I need your advice. I'm a thin guy who spends most of his time sitting (SW developer). I'm between thin and fit, and I want to get this [fit](http://91ef69bade70f992a001-b6054e05bb416c4c4b6f3b0ef3e0f71d.r93.cf3.rackcdn.com/healthy-fit-young-man-in-underwear-100305431.jpg). Basically, abs and chest.

My body:

- Age: 26
- Height: 1.79m (5' 10.5'')
- Weight: 60kg (133lbs)
- Strong legs, weak arms

Last summer **I tried** calisthenics by myself, following [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4PrF.jpg) training, 2 times a week + running 6.5km in 45 minutes. I did it during 7 months with several interruptions. **I lost** 2kg and achieved my lowest weight ever and my fittest view ever, photo <del>here</del>. However, for me 59,5kg is borderline "below ideal weight" according to BMI.

My diet:

- I eat 5 times a day (breakfast, brunch, lunch, linner, dinner) and drink less than <200ml of water
- No red meat, usually white meat (4 times a week), sometimes fish
- Always vegetables (broccoli once per week), always carbs (rice > pasta > bread > potatoes), almost no sugar, low fats (cheese, milk, yogurt)

I feel like I'm **not being effective** with my training. I can feel my abs below my belly fat, *but I can't lose any more fat!* This spring I want to start it again, but with your guidance. I can train 4 times a week.

Question:

**Which exercises do you recommend for my goal (chest, abs)?** It's hard to train chest with shaky arms (<20 push-ups straight). **Any changes on my diet?** It looks wrong to eat chicken and broccoli every day.

P.S: I don't want to get bigger, I just want to look fitter (dry body).

Comment: I think you may have fallen into the trap of "bigger = huge" which is not really the case. In any case, it is of my personal opinion that you really need to eat more and add in more resistance training to get the results you really want. Either way that's going to involve getting bigger (as you will need to add on more muscle to look "fitter"). I'd recommend starting a beginner's strength training program (Starting Strength or StrongLifts) which might help you more than you realize.

Comment: Also as an aside, I've been training for ~1.5 years now and have gained close to 20 pounds. Despite that I pretty much only look bigger than what I actually am compared to then (because of better definition), granted I started out differently than you.

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091

Comment: Eric, if you post that link as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.