# Home- chest workouts-gym bar only in floor

Tags: workout, muscle-gain

[image: this is my bar]
My food intake is proper. I want to focus only to the workouts :D
Hi there ,i want to obtain chest.I have only this gym bar as you see.In the image there are 10pounds each side.I have and more pounds.What i want to ask here ,on this same topic.First,can i obtain using this only bar a nice visible chest?Second,i will use it in floor is this bad for my back or somewhere else?Third,i will not doing everyday , i will do it monday ,after wedsnday ,friday ,sunday ,or should i do everyday? Four ,i will start 20pounds x3 ,after 24 x3 after 26 x3 and last 28 x2 or it would be better start from 28pounds ,26 ,24,what would be the preferable? Last question,in the same day should i re-doing it this program once more or more,would be giving me more results if i am doing more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is that bar, you can do three valuable lifts. Do all of them: building one part of your body up and ignoring the others will make you weak, prone to injuries, and have a funky posture.

- [Barbell overhead press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BBMilitaryPress.html). Be careful how you get it up to the "rack position", [cleaning](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/OlympicLifts/PowerClean.html) is actually a bit involved so consider setting the barbell ends on two ladders or something of the sort if you can. This will be your shoulder/chest lift and in my mind is much more valuable than bench pressing. Keep your butt and abs tight.
- [Front squat](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/OlympicLifts/FrontSquat.html). Push through your heels, keep your feet flat.
- [Barbell rows](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBBentOverRow.html). Don't always do it, but have a mirror at your side or video record (better, since you can keep your head straight) and watch for bouncing and a non-flat back (both bad).

If you do those every other day, 3x10, you'll be doing pretty good for yourself. It's not a perfect program but it's better than most. The only other thing to consider is that the weight will be different through all of them, the overhead press being easily your weakest lift.

At some point consider moving to [a more dialed in training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) but again if you can stick to the above, and avoid the temptation to focus on "mirror muscles" (the ones you can see in the mirror when you flex) you'll be looking and feeling great within a few months.

Answer (score 2):

The floor might not give you a bad back, but only training chest will *definitely* give you a bad back.

The chest muscles pull the shoulders forward. The upper back muscles pull the shoulders back. If you train only chest, your shoulders will be pulled forward, your chest will get caved in, and your back muscles will get very tense and sore.

[image]

You will invariably end up like in the picture to the left.

Comment: No no ! I am not training only chest.What i mean on my question ,is how to train only the part of chest at floor.I didnt meant the only workout i do is chest