# What are the best excises to do in gym for beginners

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines

I'm going to gym from 3days.I'm doing thread mill for 15min and cycling for 15 min ,another cross machine for 15min and some exercises.I'm also doing abs for only 5min .totally I'm spending 1hour time in gym and also I'm following diet as instructed by my trainer.
Now I'm 67kgs n my height was 5.2
Is this exercises are enough..r I need to improve ?
I also want to know what are the best exercises to do in gym to burn more calories.
How much time beginners can spend in gym ?
Today I did for 1hr 45min,still I'm willing to do..can I do ?
Doing abs daily is necessary ?
Plz let me know 
ThnQ

Comment: This is personal preference - but for me, the quickest way the shred fat / focus on fat burning is to do 45 / 30 seconds average speed, on say the bike - and then complete the remainder of the minute (so 15 / 30 seconds) at fast pace. Repeat this for as long as you can go on for. When i first started i could do this for 20 minutes and couldnt carry on - Now could do it for an hour easily. Give it a try.

Comment: No you don't need to do abs everyday. If you want to get toned abs you'll have to work them out a few times a week but not everyday. The main part of getting lean is burning calories and ab exercises don't burn a whole lot of them.

Comment: I feel like this is too broad of a question with too many opinions versus something objtective.

Comment: For terminology's sake: @Goralight described an example of "High-Intensity Interval Training" (HIIT).

Comment: Thats the name.. I completely forgot the name of it when writting, Thanks @CCCV for the correct name!

Comment: Let's end a common misconception.  There are no "best" anything when it comes to fitness training.  What works for one individual may not work for another.  It's up to each individual to decide what training routines and exercise are the most beneficial for themselves.  Any offered suggestions are merely opinions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good strength training program for a beginner?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/whats-a-good-strength-training-program-for-a-beginner)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to lose body fat, the first thing I'm going to assume is that you are otherwise healthy. I don't know how old you are, I don't know what condition your heart is in. That's up to you to figure out with your doctor. So with that massive caveat:

The best way to lose fat is to restrict your carb intake, and completely stop all sugar intake. No soda, no sweets of any kind, and NO alcohol. Check every packaged thing you buy because even yogurt has loads of sugar in it.

Do NOT restrict your calories though. You need to keep your calorie intake on par with the workouts your doing. Compensate for low carb intake with more good fats, and more protein.

Diet is the most important thing, start there first, get that into your daily habbit, then move to exercise. The reason I say this is because no matter what you do in the gym, it's simply not possible to "burn off" what you eat. Your body is far too efficient. An hour of all out intense exercise, might burn 500 calories. A single burger and you've just wiped out all that work.

SO, the way around this is to focus on exercises that cause your base level metabolism to rise for extended periods of time. This will burn a few extra calories every hour for a day or so, which adds up to far more than you can burn in a single exercise session.

There are two primary categories of exercises that do this: interval prints, and heavy weight training. It's really up to you which one two focus on. For most people who have no strength ambitions, interval sprints are best.

To perform interval sprints, take any exercise, treadmill, bike, running up a hill, literally anything working your whole legs, and perform a set as hard and fast as you can for 30 seconds. Then rest 60-90 seconds and repeat. You should only need 3-5 sets at most because as you get better at this your intensity will naturally climb so there is no need to endlessly add sets.

That being said, take it easy the first few times to let your body get accustom to this form of exercise. Also, don't go all out on your first set, use it as a warmup.

Training this way will cause your metabolism to rise for the next ~48-72 hours (it's highly variable, don't get to caught up in that). That's it.

If your interested in strength, ask another question and I'll answer it there as I believe for most people the interval sprints are the best option.

If you are able to stick with the very simple diet I outlined for you, that will be the majority of your results. The interval sprints will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Studies**

According to [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23019316), aerobic training is the most efficient in order to lose overall body mass and fat mass. However if you want to retain the most amount of muscle, they advise to engage in Resistance Training.

**Personal experience**

On a more personal note, I used to do quite a bit of reps and sets with lost of different isolation movements. This lead me to have a low body mass and metabolism. I was eating around 2000 kilocalories a day.
When I switched to strength training, I was doing half the time in training, but only focusing on big movements (Squats variations, Press variations and Deadlift variations).
As a result, my time spent training went down, my strength exploded and my metabolism followed the same path. I was eating 4000 kcals a day, still not gaining weight. Sleep patterns were perfect too.
As a side note, it took some time before eating 4000 kcals a day without gaining weight. I had to go up over time, starting at 2500, gradually increasing.

> I also want to know what are the best exercises to do in gym to burn more calories

Therefore, as your goal is to burn more calories, I would suggest doing what I do now. Focusing on bit compound movements, and spend less time in the gym as a result.
A good program would be [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/).
If you are interested, here is a typical day of training of me (not like Starting Strength though):

- Front Squat, up to one top set of 5 - takes about 15 minutes
- Bench press, up to one top set of 5 - takes about 10 minutes
- Behind the neck Push press, up to one top set of 5 - takes about 10 minutes
- Good morning, up to one top set of 20 - takes about 10 minutes

Total time: 45 minutes. I do that 3-4 times a week. Need around 3000-3500 kcals a day right now to maintain bodyweight.

I'm a male, 23yo, 5'10 (177 cm) and 167 pounds (76kg).

I hope this helps !

Idriss