# Is this good or not

Tags: routine

I need some help. I made a plan for my exercises and they go like this.

- Monday-biceps,1 hour
- Tuesday-chest,1 hour
- Wednesday-Rest
- Thursday-shoulders,1 hour
- Friday-triceps,1 hour
- Rest
- Rest

I do abdominal workouts at home as well as pressups and other sorts of exercises when the group recovers but I don't do it at gym. I want to know if this is a good setup as I am getting a good rest interval between each specific muscle group.

Comment: Consider concentrating on effective training programs that have proven results. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing your goals. The routine to follow will substantially different for strength and for mass.

Answer (score 4):

For biceps whole week to rest is way too much. Chest usually needs 2 days of rest. Your front actons of deltoids can be a bit tired, during shoulders day. Well, that also depends on your age.

I can't see legs, back here. Even if you don't want to build them up - that is good for testosterone level, at least. So your chest can gain from that.

To be more precise I need to know what you are doing during each training.

Answer (score 4):

No, regardless of your goals, that is not a good workout routine.

a) No leg work, b) no back work, c) too much pushing work, d) too much arm work.

Assuming from your question that you can train on Monday / Tuesday / Thursday / Friday, then you'd be much better doing either a push / pull split, or an upper lower split.

How this would look is either:

- Monday - Light / moderate pull
- Tuesday - Light / moderate push
- Thursday - Heavy pull
- Friday - Heavy push

(for a routine, something [like this](https://www.t-nation.com/workouts/push-pull-workout), but with the days swapped slightly so you get more rest after the heavy pull / heavy push days)

OR

- Monday - Upper
- Tuesday - Lower
- Thursday - Upper
- Friday - Lower

(I'm not going to give you a specific one, just [have a search around, there's too many to count](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=upper%20lower%20split))

If you go with your current routine, you're going to be limiting your muscle growth potential by not doing some of the major compound exercises, you're going to give yourself shoulder issues because of the lack of pulling exercises to offset the pushing and even if neither of those come to pass, you're going to end up looking like [Johnny Bravo](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=johnny%20bravo) (and very probably be laughed at for your lack of legs).