# Underweight female-gym routines?

Tags: muscle-gain

So, I am 5'4" and weigh 90 pound (20 yrs old).  I went to the gym for the first time today and well, for squats I can't even lift the bar itself. As for the leg press, I can do it but not with any weights on. And on the other machines I can do them but not with added weights. I figure if I go often maybe I could work myself up to weights? I figure maybe if I build muscle I'll weigh more.  I'm new to all of this so any tips or advice or routine would be nice. I did the squat machine where the bar doesn't come off, but i hurt my back doing that. I don't think I'm quite ready for it? :/

Maybe i could do squats just with dumbbells or something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's very normal that a girl of only 90lbs will have trouble picking up the bar since it's 45lbs, which is half your bodyweight. Anyone would have issues picking up half their bodyweight when they just start out lifting.

You can absolutely become stronger and gain weight if this is your goal, you'll need a few things in order to get there:

**Consistency:** This point can't be over stressed. Being consistent in the things I'm about to list will be the key factor.

**The right mindset:** Don't think this is going to happen over night. Make a plan for atleast 6 to 12 months, this is a sport of patience. This will help in having realistic expectations.

**Diet:** Having a healthy diet is going to be one of the most important things here. Your body will need fuel to grow and become stronger therefore eating enough and eating healthy is very important.

**Working out:** Start out with weights you can handle and do all exercises with proper form. Mastering the basics with smaller weights will create a proper foundation for you to strive from when you become stronger. Going heavier just because you want to live heavy weight will only hurt your progress in the long run.

If this means only doing bodyweight squats at first, this is fine! Loads of people can't even do 10 bodyweight squats so if you can even do this, it will help you work towards doing squats with added weight.

---

The only thing I can't answer right now is the back pain issue, where does it hurt? Does the bar simply hurt on top of your shoulders? Or did you feel pain in your lower back?

I hope this helps, let me know!

Comment: I got pain in my lower back @mjb

Comment: @Jaena This is because either your form is incorrect, or your lower back is not strong enough to balance the weight. You should consult a personal trainer in your local gym to make sure you're form is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really advocate for sticking with the right lifts and getting the form dialed in: the weight amount really doesn't matter other than convenience of being able to walk up the 45lb olympic bar and use it or more.

So here's what I'd star with:

- [Goblet squats](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/GluteusMaximus/DBFrontSquat.html). You can use kettlebells or dumbells, and that way you can start with as much weight as is comfortable for you and dial in your form. Once you can have 20lb dumbells in each hand you're ready to move on over to the olympic bar.
- Start looking into [proven strength training programs](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) and emulate those lifts as best you can. Goblet squats until barbell back squats, [dumbbell presses](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/DBShoulderPress.html) until barbell overhead press, and [single stiff leg deadlifts](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/GluteusMaximus/DBSingleLegStiffLegDeadlift.html) until you can tackle the full bar. And then with the full bar, put it up on risers (boxes maybe, get creative) so that the bar is at a height that's ~9" off the ground.

There's nothing fundamentally different about strength training between men and women, most of it just revolves around some techniques in the beginning until you're able to handle the full bar.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Start with your body weight exercises. Lady push ups, then normal push ups. Forward/backward lunges, for legs. Keep back straight, do not bend it forward, and do not move front knee off toes. Maybe two small dumbbells in your hands just to have better posture. If that sounds complicated - ask for help - one hour per week with personal trainer can help a lot. Plank is other exercise I would propose. Try to start with something called full body workout. That mean - every time all muscles are trained. Put 'Full body sample workout for girl" into google. For me [that](https://www.bodybuilding.com/content/womens-strength-training-guide.html) was one of the first results. Read, try if it works for you. If not - just ask another question. WE will be more then happy to answer.

There are two main points, or tips here. Changing body is long process, it takes months to have results. You are young, so it can faster, but still - all is about small steps. Every week worked counts, and next January, someone else will start. And then you will see how much you have done. Next tip - it is quite easy to get injured. Thats why I'm insisting on small steps. Watch your body, if something is painful - understand why, and what to do with it. Trainer can help, but at the end it is you, and your body, so be sure you understand each other. ;)

I assume that your back pain is in the place where bar was... if so then you can roll towel over the bar. There are foams to put on the bar as well. You body was not prepared for that, tissues got squeezed, so there is pain, perhaps bruises as well. With time, it will be better, after 2-3 months you will do it without a problem. Squat is complex exercise, so I would advise to ask trainer, or someone to watch, and tell you if everything is OK. Trainers are there, so you can talk with them. From time to time, they can look and give you a hint. If that is too often, or that person see much work - paid training will be proposed.

To select best trainer - talk with some of them, talk with other people at the gym - if you like trainer, and other people says his is known to be good. At least that is not random choice.