# Powerlift/strongman program for beginner?

Tags: stronglifts, powerlifting

Im 270lb 6'2, starting back into the gym, i've gone 4 times now.

I've always wanted to see if I could excel in max strength and strongmen type of lifts.

I've seen this [What's a good strength training program for a beginner?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/whats-a-good-strength-training-program-for-a-beginner)

Would this info be a good start? Im going to start the Stronglifts 5x5.

I dont care about looking good, I just want good form and the ability to lift heavier and heavier stuff every time.

I watch some calgarybarbell on youtube and been trying deadlift and sumo deadlifts my 1MR is 235.

I also can't do squats, when I was younger in weights class, my neck area couldn't handle the weight and now I dont have the range of motion right now to hold the bar.

Let me know if I need more info and I am new so correct me where Im wrong, even if its mindset, I want a good foundation.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that in the beginning take it easy and get a good feeling for your body and what is the correct form. When you hit heavier weights more focus will be needed to maintain form. Starting strength and stronglifts are great programs to start with.

Get some good sources on how to establish and maintain proper form through all the lifts. Sources like Mark Rippetoe, other power/weightlifters. I enjoyed the Starting Strength book because it dives into biomechanics of the lifts, it's well written and simple to understand. I would also refer you to jtsstrength.com, great articles and other material from great athletes. If you like to watch videos on YT then check Alan Thrall, Bret Contreras etc. There is a ton of great people, just filter the garbage.

Could you explain a bit more regarding your "neck area"? During the low-bar squat the bar rests on your upper back muscles around your scapula. Your neck muscles and mobility shouldn't play a key role here unless you have some other non disclosed issues with your spine/muscles in this specific area.

Comment: I can't rest the bar on my upper back muscles and grab the bar at the same time. the bar rides up. i've tried using the squat cages and just even setting myself into a empty bar doesnt feel comfortable and ends up resting more in the neck area and not in the upper back muscles.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what could be your problem but I'm assuming you have poor shoulder mobility. Check out this setup taught by Mark Rippetoe [link]https://youtu.be/QhVC_AnZYYM?t=186[link]. Try to grip the bar so far apart that you can rest the bar on the scapular muscles and not on the neck. As Rippetoe says, shouldn't feel comfortable but also shouldn't be painful. Try to achieve as much tightness in your upper back as possible. Start squating w/ light weights like this and shorten the grip every week. You will see improvements. Check out also Kelly Starretts shoulder mobility routines.

Comment: I have started to incorporate the mobility exercises. TY. I can finally rest the bar on my back but I have to use a squat rack with the rails. Appreciate the help.