# I need suggestion about gym workout

Tags: exercise

I'm male, my height is 5.6" and my weight is 78 kg. I already going to gym for 2 month (4 days a week) , I want to change my program, what is the best program for me? It hard for me to do it alone, because i can't affort to pay any trainer.

What i did so far :

Monday  : chest
Tuesday : Back
Thursday : Shoulder
Friday : Chest

Btw, i have fat in my stomach.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Well. i just want to have nice looking body with some muscle. There are a lot of things that i use barbell and dumbbell and machine too. Thanks for answer btw.

Comment: You're not going to have a nice looking body if you don't train legs.

Comment: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two major flaws in your program.

For a start there is no mention of diet. Especially if you have a fat stomach you want to be dieting and eating clean to see results.

Secondly you're missing arms and legs in your workouts, I recommend doing one of the most common splits

1)Back and biceps

2)Chest and Triceps

3) Shoulders

4) Legs

Or something along these lines, You don't need money to afford a trainer to make results. **All** the information you need is online.

Comment: Another issue was the duplication of chest workouts. I completely agree with this answer!

Comment: Your answer did add legs and arms but no core, is there a reason for that?

Comment: @MJB Depends on the person, through training with strict form keeping core tight my abs are quite strong without training them and are visible. Depends on what you do

Comment: I guess it depends on what you define as strong. How do you know your abs are strong if you don't work them? Like how do you measure what strong is? I'm just curious because the word core literally means "the most essential part". Neglecting it wouldn't be smart in my eyes. Also by core I mean more than just the six abs that are located at the front of your abdominal area.

Comment: Well I box so it's completely different I train there, but the original ab strength test was the leg raise on the flaw keeping your lower back touching the ground at all angles of the movement. As I say it depends on the person and there are plenty of body builders who do not train abs then cut weight do a bit of abs and they have them visible. It depends on your goals if you want to be aesthetic then yes of course train your core. But training for an occasion is what a large amount of people do

Comment: @MJB, regarding your question of on a strong core, many Strength coaches would tell you "If you are able to squat the bar equal to your body weight for 5 reps - you have a strong core". Similarly, many people don't explicitly train forearms in order to increase their grip strength. They just lift heavy things and the grip trains with other movements, like deadlifts or pullups.

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the response. I wouldn't consider squatting your bodyweight for 5 reps strong so maybe my perception is just different/wrong. I wouldn't even consider benching your bodyweight for 5 reps strong so yeah maybe that's just me being a little crazy.

Comment: @MJB, you are right. I should've put strong in quotations, as in "strong", simply because the strong could mean different things for different people. My point was that you can develop "strong" core by doing other things that require you to have a "strong" core. Hence, it is not an absolutely needed to train core separately, at least at the early stages of weightlifting, which is the case for the author of the question. Nevertheless, I do train core because I like it :)

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thanks for answer . For now i do biceps and triceps workouts every times i go to gym. Is that wrong ?

Comment: @Boby, it is unnecessary. Concentrate on bigger, compound movements (squats/pullups/pushups/etc.)

Comment: @Boby Also increased chance for injury. If you are able to train arms every day without pain or fatigue likely you're not training hard enough or correctly

Answer (score 3):

To add to an answer by Twyxz, 
I would switch the order of the split a bit, given your weekly schedule:

- **Mon**:   Back and biceps
- **Tues**:  Chest and Triceps
- **Thurs**: Legs
- **Fri**:   Shoulders

Also, how many reps and sets you do, will play a major role in what **kind** of a result you will get. Try to do more compound movements rather than isolation ones. 
Generally (note, these are just the guidelines):

- 3-6  - Strength
- 6-12 - Hypertrophy
- 12+ - Endurance

Diet will probably play a bigger role in your body composition though. So, do try to eat better(whatever "better" means to you).

Comment: Just as a personal preference, I would switch the bi/triceps days. I prefer to work the triceps (pushing/extension) with the back and biceps (pull/flexion) with the chest. That way they aren't fatigued from the compound movements. YMMV, that is certainly not a show stopper.

Comment: @JohnP, I've done that before as well, also helps to separate push/pull by another day, that way bi/tri have time to recover.

Comment: Have to agree with @JohnP here. I've been doing that for a while and it really works out better for me on the long run.